# Fig kafka hostPort mapping

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, fig

I would like to use fig with kafka to manage a kafka cluster.

I'm a beginner with fig and I have a problem with hostPort mapping.

I use kafka-docker as kafka image. My fig.yml is here:

```
zookeeper:
  image: jplock/zookeeper:3.4.6
  ports:
    - "2181"
kafka:
  image: wurstmeister/kafka:0.8.1.1-1
  ports:
    - "9092"
  links:
    - zookeeper:zk
  environment:
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 192.168.59.103
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

It's the exemple given with the image.

Now, here is my problem:

I run this command to launch a cluster:

> fig scale kafka=2

I create a kafka topic like this:

> ./kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper 192.168.59.103:49157
>   --replication-factor 2 --partitions 1 --topic test

Next:

> $ ./kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper 192.168.59.103:49157
>   --topic test2 Topic:test2 PartitionCount:1    ReplicationFactor:2 Configs:    Topic:
>   test2 Partition: 0    Leader: 49158   Replicas: 49159,49158   Isr: 49159,49158

Now my figKakfa_2 crashes for some reasons (it run on 49159 port).

How can I restart this container with the same port ?

If I run again the scale command, I get a new container but mapped on another hostPort and the zookeeper doesn't get it as the old instance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `net: host` in your fig.yml all your docker containers will use the host's network stack, no need to expose ports. This means they won't change on restart or scale up down. You need to figure out how to get your kafka instances to use unique ports.

http://www.fig.sh/yml.html

Comment: With net: "bridge" (default value) it work. With net: "host" => Recreating figKafka_kafka_1...
Cannot start container 26b3c9472f027cde8ca8a01fc4d3fde03fb3e6543696dae3421a438ed0ae6ee0:  (exit status 2)

Comment: Ok I found this https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/5835 net: host option doesn't work with link :(

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is not to expose ports on the host, but access your kafkas on their container's IP (like 172.17.0.3 or something like this) on port 9092. You can inspect a containers IP by `$ docker inspect --format "{{json .NetworkSettings.Networks}}" <container id/name>`.